# What to use as website size?

Tags: css

I am busy building a website and I thought what should I use as height/width?

And then I got a bit confused I heard everyone saying 1024 * 768 .. but which one whas the width and what whas te height..

So is it :
Height 1024 * width 768 Or
width 1024 * height 768 ?

Or is there a new better size to build youre website on?

If there is an duplicate I missed please post it and I will look there.

P.S
Thanks everyone for the help I have got in al my questions before this.

Comment: There's a browser display stats: http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_display.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They would mean:

> Width = 1024px
>
> Height = 768px

Generally `x * y` means `width * height`

Answer (score 1):

First one is the width.

The "new better size" is to make the site scale for all sizes above some absurd minimum. This will also make it accessible and zoomable.

Comment: You mean that the sites detect which screen resolution you have and they layout is fitted to that?

Comment: no. they are made with html and css in such a manner that the site will adjust to any browser window size.

Comment: Read about responsive web design http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_Web_Design

Comment: Thank you for that link, Responsive web design is really really awesome. But a bit to far for me now. But I will use it soon as I learned it.

Answer (score 0):

1024 width and 768 height. Its standard resolution on PC, notebooks. Its recomended to create sites that fits on its resolution.